# Fix Datapack Glitch

Tags: pc, batman-arkham-origins

Is there a way to fix the Enigma Pack glitch? I have 2 Data Packs that show up on my map but I've 100% already collected. I've restarted the game a few times but it's just not showing up. I've defeated all the informers and collected everything but these 2. Is there a way to fix this or get around this?

I'm playing it via PC / Steam, Windows 8 - 64bit

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few datapacks that are literally on top of each other.

I thought multiple times that my game was glitched but after following a guide going to literally every datapack location I realized that I was under the mistaken impression that a datapack indicator was for one I had already gotten, when in reality it was indicating there were two in the same location at different heights.

I am not saying there is no way you are glitched, but in most cases there is another one somewhere else.

Comment: The research I've found is pretty much everybody on the PC is running into this problem and it's yet to be patched. Quick google search brought up TENS of articles. The answer I've found is just to get to new+ and they will respawn. Not much of an answer and more of a comment IMO.

Comment: Where are the two you are referring to located? Have other people had problems with the same datapacks?